# jQuery .trigger() individually <select> menu

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, html

I have a jQuery/AJAX function that when triggered from a `<select>` menu change posts data to a php query and returns results. The results are placed in the `<td><label class=count>` on the same row as the `<select>` menu in my table. The function works just fine when the select menu is changed but I also want to trigger this function on page load. I have tried using `.trigger(change);` at the end of my code but all that does is place the results (2 in this case because there only two table rows) in the `<td><label class=count>` on the last row instead of placing the result in that cell of the parent row. Can someone help me get the function to run on page load, but the results in the `<td><label class=count>` of the same row as the select menu that triggered the result?

Here is jQuery:

```
<script type="text/javascript"> 
$(document).ready(function(){

$('.typeval').change(function(){
    var movement    =  $(this).val();
    var client_id   = $(this).parent().siblings().find('.clientval').val();
    var class_id    = <? echo $class_id; ?>;
        $count      = $(this).parents('tr').find('label.count');

$.ajax({ 
  type: "POST",
  url: "movement_count.php",
  data: {movement:movement, client_id:client_id, class_id:class_id},
  dataType: "json", 
  success:(function(output) {

      $.each(output, function(index, value){
      //alert(value);
      $count.append(output[index]);
      }) // each

   }) // success

}); // ajax

  }); // .typeval

});  // document

</script>
```

Here is part of the HTML table:

```
 <tr>
    <td><input type="hidden" name="client_id[]" class="clientval" value="1"></td>
    <td><input type="hidden" name="order[]" value="1A">1A</td>
    <td><select name="movement[]" width=200 class="typeval"></select></td>
    <td><input type="hidden" name="rest[]" value="Rest">Rest</td>
    <td><label class="count"></label></td>
</tr>

<tr>
   <td><input type="hidden" name="client_id[]" class="clientval" value="8"></td>
   <td><input type="hidden" name="order[]" value="1A">1A</td>
   <td><select name="movement[]" width=200 class="typeval"></select></td>
   <td><input type="hidden" name="rest[]" value="Rest">Rest</td>
   <td><label class="count"></label></td>
</tr>
```

Here is the movement_count.php

```
<?php

include('core/init.php');
protect_page();


$class_id = $_POST['class_id'];


if (isset($_POST['client_id'])){
$xmovement = x_move_performed($class_id, $_POST['client_id'], $_POST['movement']);

    echo json_encode ($xmovement);   
} // isset      


?>
```

Here is the php function that queries the db and returns a number(COUNT)

```
function x_move_performed($class_id, $client_id, $movement){
$class_id = (int)$class_id;
$client_id = (int)$client_id;

$query = "SELECT COUNT(`movement`) FROM `completed_movements` WHERE `class_id` = $class_id AND `client_id` = $client_id AND `movement` = '$movement'";
$res = mysql_query($query);
$result = mysql_fetch_assoc($res);
return $result;
}
```

Comment: You're missing a semicolon at the end of your `$.each...`

Comment: @Shmiddty semicolon is not required in JS.

Comment: Can you show us the code that triggers the change event plz?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try to make the ajax synchronous:

```
async: false
```

Comment: this just give a different result but not the right one. This runs the function on the first row but places on in the last row, it then runs the next row but replaces the result from the first...all results still only showing in the last row of table.

Comment: this latest edit returns the value of the 1st row `select` menu and not the query result...it still places it in the last row of the table.

Comment: Sure, the callback in the ajax function was returning after the onload change function executes. hence, it wasnt able to locate $count. making the ajax synchronous, it waits for the callback to return, and then finishes execution.